# How to run only a part of the DAG in Airflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-2.x

Is it possible to run **only a part of the DAG** in Airflow?

I know one can run a single task. But is it possible to run a set of linked tasks within the DAG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can link different tasks, create conditions, loops, etc.

I recommend taking a look at this link. It's really well documented -> [Tasks Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/tasks.html)